# How to standardise NaOH?

Tags: acid-base, experimental-chemistry, titration

My aim is to "To determine the concentration of citric acid in lemon juice using titration technique." and as following i need to standardise the NaOH in order to titrate it with validity. Is there a procedure and step to standardising NaOH. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should find it in any analytic chemistry textbook, considering volumetric methods. 
We did so in the high school.

In short, a solution of known molar concentration of well defined acidic substance is made, that get titrated by the $\ce{NaOH}$ solution.

Typically oxalic acid $\ce{(COOH)_2 . 2 H2O}$, weighted at good scales, preparing solution $\pu{0.05 mol / l}$.

When you Google "acidimetric titration sodium hydroxide oxalic acid" , you get tons of references, from illustrating videos to PDF documents.

Comment: You might have used oxalic acid in high school, but potassium hydrogen phthalate (KHP) is the go to primary standard.  You dry it in an oven before use. // I can't imagine a hydrate being used for serious work.

Comment: It frequently  used in universities and lab praxis  as well.Potassium hydrogen phthalate is primary standard for pH. Hydrates are used often, if they are well defined. Another example of a hydrate standard  is the Mohr salt $\ce{(NH4)_2Fe(SO4)2.6H20}$ for oxidimetry as a stable source of $\ce{Fe^{II}}$

Comment: I mentioned oxalic acid as even since high school ( chemical  industry oriented), not only in high school. The acid is used since a dawn of volumetric. In fact, I do not remember, if we ever used KHP for that purpose.

Comment: Additionally, KHP is less suitable for the particular $\ce{NaOH}$ case, due its rather high $\mathrm{p}K_{a2} = 5.51$, compared to the $\ce{(COOH)_2}$  $\mathrm{p}K_{a2} = 1.27$  and $\mathrm{p}K_{a2} = 4.27$.          


As it would interefere with $\ce{H2O + CO2 <=> H+ + HCO3^-}$ ( of $\ce{Na2CO3}$ origin ) with the apparent  $\mathrm{p}K_{app} = 6.35$

Comment: Using KHP and phenolphthalein works fine to standardize NaOH. For both KHP and oxalic acid you'd need to boiled distilled water to remove dissolved CO2 from atmosphere.

Comment: Using KHP with FF converts undefined amount of Na2CO3 to NaHCO3.

Comment: I don't understand. What is "FF"?

Comment: Phenolphthalein ( I am broking my fingers typing it ) . I apologize, it is a common abbreviation among Czech chemists, as we write it with F. I have forgotten that and it could confuse you.

Comment: So what indicator would you use with oxalic acid when NaOH is the titrant?

Comment: In 80s, we titrated NaOH by HOx on methyl orange (3.1-4.4) I guess. When yellow showed hints of red, we stopped and heated the solution to strip it from CO2 from Na2CO3. Then we cooled it down. It turned back to yellow, but the red titration end was already close.

Comment: Hm, When I think about it , it would match rather HCl. HOx would be probably reversed, on the PhPht as well, as you suggested.

Comment: I've asked the question about oxalic acid -- https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/111646/is-oxalic-acid-dihydrate-considered-a-primary-acid-standard-in-analytical-chemis